# Vue: wrong backgroud color on component

Tags: html, css, vue.js

I have a file with global color variables:

**colors.scss**:

```
$darkest: #36383F;
$font-color-light: #DCDDDE;
$yellow-light: #FEE500;
```

and components that use those:

```
<template>
    <div class="text-breakdown">
        <h3>Text Breakdown</h3>

        <input type="text"/>

        <button type="submit">Breakdown</button>
    </div>


</template>

<style lang="scss" scoped>
    @import "../scss/colors.scss";

    .text-breakdown  {
        background-color: $yellow-light;
        width: 80%;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        align-items: center;
    }

    input  {
        width: 500px;
        height: 250px;
        border: none;
        text-decoration: none;
    }

    button  {

    }

</style>
```

**App.vue**:

```
<template>
    <div class="text-breakdown">
        <h3>Text Breakdown</h3>

        <input type="text"/>

        <button type="submit">Breakdown</button>
    </div>


</template>

<style lang="scss" scoped>
    @import "../scss/colors.scss";

    .text-breakdown  {
        background-color: $yellow-light;
        width: 80%;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        align-items: center;
    }

    input  {
        width: 500px;
        height: 250px;
        border: none;
        text-decoration: none;
    }

    button  {

    }

</style>
```

When I go to the page the color is yellow, but the exact color is not `#FEE500`, but rather `#FEE63E`
[image]

Comment: Color which is getting rendered is #FEE63E ? But it should have been #FEE500

Comment: @JithinB Yes. You can see it from the picture I've attached

Comment: Will it be possible for you upload a working demo

Comment: I added the App.vue you could copypaste. To my knowledge, things like jsfiddle don't process vue projects? And it looks like having to do with vue

Comment: Try debugging by giving the variable $darkest, does the exact color render in that case ?

Comment: Yes, the $darkest always renders correctly - can be seen from the pic too

Comment: Are you checking the output colour in the dev console? Just asking as if you were to check it with e.g. a colour picker, then the element's opacity might have an effect on the rendered colour.

Comment: There maybe a chance $yellow-light is a bootstrap variable ( if you are using Bootstrap ) , then you need to correctly import files in a particular order to overwrite bootstrap variables. To check that , just change the name of the variable from $yellow-light to some other name and try

Comment: this demo code should work. [check this demo of your code](https://codesandbox.io/s/serene-shadow-ign2i)

Comment: Unfortunatelly, not. I changed the variable name to `$yellow-light2020: #FEE500;` and it's still `#FEE63E`.

Comment: #FEE500 - Try giving the same in rgb format and see what happens, rgb - rgb(254, 229, 0)